# Update using Select Query in Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have an table employee

```
DeptID  Name
1       manu
2       kiran
3       anu
4       manoj
0       peter
0       Kumar
0       mike
```

have one more  table  called Department

```
DeptID  DepName
1        CS
2        IS
3        EE 
0        RR
```

Query

```
update employee
set DeptID = 7 where  exists(   
SELECT * FROM   Department WHERE (DeptID = 0))
```

**by Exceuting this  Query the result set  changes all the DepID in employee table  to  7**

i wanted  to  change only DeptID  to  7 where  the DeptID is  "0".
This is an exaple i am trying to tell you. in my real Databse i have  got an problem like this

please  help me out  how  to solve the problem 
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
update employee
set DeptID = 7 where  exists(   
SELECT * FROM   Department WHERE (DeptID = 0))
where DeptID = 0
```

You have to add one more condition to your update statement.

If you are just updating all employee who have DeptID = 0 to 7, then you need not use subquery too. the below query will do -

```
update employee
set DeptID = 7
where DeptID = 0
```

Comment: TRIED THE ABOVE ITS  GIVING   ERROR TELLING MISPLACED OF WHERE CONDITION

Comment: @Prince23 - Can you try the second query in my answer and check if that is what you want to do?

Comment: @Prince23 - can you explain a little more detail on what your want? I think I might not have understood what you really require.

Answer (score 0):

This will set all DeptID in employee to 7 where DeptID is 0

```
update Employee
set DeptID = 7
where DeptID = 0
```

`Employee.DeptID` is probably a foreign key from `Department.DeptID` so you must first make sure that there exists a `Department` with `DeptID = 7`.

In your sample data you have a department named 'RR'. If that is the one you want to use but with DeptID = 7 you can do like this.

```
-- Add Department with DeptID = 7
insert into Department(DeptID, DepName)
select 7, DepName
from Department
where DeptID = 0

-- Change DeptID to 7 for Employee's with DeptID = 0
update Employee
set DeptID = 7
where DeptID = 0

-- Delete Department
delete Department
where DeptID = 0
```

**Edit 1** This will work as well but I do not see the point of using it. Your update statement modified to only update employee's with `DeptID=0`

```
update employee
set DeptID = 7
where
  exists(select *
         from Department
         where (DeptID = 0)) and
  DeptID = 0
```

Comment: hey Mikael, the  above is  something siliar i have in the live DB i  wanted  do  like the one   above  said.

Comment: @prince23 - Sorry, I do not understand what you want. Is it the update statement that is wrong? I thought you wanted to replace DeptID with 7 for the rows where DeptID is 0. Is that not the case?